how to write a function with unknown number of input in python?
I would like to write a function keeping the common index of input dataframes. I could write it as follows for 2 dataframes:
def get_df_common_index(df1, df2):
    common_index = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
    return df1.loc[common_index], df2.loc[common_index]

My question is how to make it a general function which can take multiple inputs and return dataframes accordingly? As if I could use it as follows:
df1, df2, df3, df4 = get_df_common_index(df1, df2, df3, df4)


Take a look at What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?

@wim is correct, more specifically, using *args, and **kwargs.
